# Regex in Java failed to match

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm writing an Android app in which I would need a Regex check for a data received through Bluetooth.

The data expression is supposed to be `A= 137, B= 137, C= 138, D= 136, E= 134, F= 138, G= 137` for every received line. I would like to first be sure the data matches " A= ddd, B= ddd.....G= ddd" while d, the value could be 0-1023. Then, extracting the value of A to G and put them into arrays of A to G. I have tried to match it but it fails all the time. I know there is a check regex function in Android studio, and I did use online websites for checking too. They all matches but fails in the app.

Could anyone help? Below is the data received and matching from bluetooth socket.

```
 void beginListenForData()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"begin for listening");
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"runnable thread");
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                           // Log.d(TAG,"incoming data is available");
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    Log.d(TAG, "data = " + data);
                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            textView.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });


                                    if (data.matches("A= \\d*, B= \\d*, C= \\d*, D= \\d*, E= \\d*, F= \\d*, G= \\d*")){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "data matches");
                                        Pattern dataA = Pattern.compile("(?<== )\\d*");
                                        Matcher matcherA = dataA.matcher(data);

                                        Log.d(TAG, matcherA.group());


                                    }else{
                                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                textView.setText("invalid data");
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
```

Edit: 
for the print out of data from `Log.d(TAG, "data = " + data);`:

```
2020-02-14 00:43:21.768 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 137, B= 138, C= 142, D= 138, E= 139, F= 138, G= 138
2020-02-14 00:43:21.841 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 137, B= 138, C= 141, D= 137, E= 136, F= 134, G= 138
2020-02-14 00:43:21.971 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 138, B= 139, C= 140, D= 139, E= 138, F= 138, G= 136
2020-02-14 00:43:22.080 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 138, B= 140, C= 138, D= 137, E= 133, F= 139, G= 139
2020-02-14 00:43:22.183 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 138, B= 137, C= 139, D= 139, E= 138, F= 138, G= 138
2020-02-14 00:43:22.287 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 139, B= 138, C= 139, D= 137, E= 138, F= 139, G= 141
2020-02-14 00:43:22.398 5130-5297/com.example.insoleapp D/Signal Fragment: data = A= 140, B= 137, C= 141, D= 138, E= 137, F= 137, G= 140
```

Comment: When posting failing code here, please describe *how* it fails. Try to create an MCVE rather than posting the whole application.

Comment: I don't see you printing out the `data` string either, how do you know that the input is correct?

Comment: Thanks Maarten for your recommendation. 
I have thought about just putting the Regex and my matching string here, but as I said, I have tested it on different platforms, and it seems ok (i.e. the expression matches the string).. I'm suspending if the problem comes from the way I collect data from bluetooth, therefore I put the whole function here for investigation.

Comment: Thanks again, I have put the printout data in the question in the edited session

Comment: Maybe your data e.g. ends with a `00` byte, which gets decoded into a `0000` character. This happens a lot when you go from native to Java. Any control characters in your string will put you on the wrong foot. Try to first `trim()` your string: "Returns a string whose value is this string, with all leading and trailing space removed, where space is defined as any character whose codepoint is less than or equal to 'U+0020' (the space character)." If it works, you may want to consider generating the string over the correct data, of course.

Comment: Thanks so much! It really works now. I didn't notice the problem and even I print data and data.trim(), there are both the same!

Comment: Posted it as answer, glad you got it solved. Never bad to look at the binary rather than the text.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving your strings from binary data. That means that they may contain characters that are not printable characters, but control characters. Those are not matched against your expression, so the expression fill fail.

The main one to be concerned about is the `00` end-of-string character that is commonly used in C environments and possibly assembly. These are often copied into Java strings by mistake at the JNI level, or by luckless developers themselves. Java string objects have an explicit size and don't rely on the ugly null-terminator.

To get rid of the control characters at the end you can call `String#trim()` so that the control characters are removed. From the JavaDoc:

> Returns a string whose value is this string, with all leading and trailing space removed, where space is defined as any character whose codepoint is **less than or equal to 'U+0020'** (the space character).

And control characters such as these are below `0x0020`.

However, you're of course better off creating your `String` without such control characters or end-of-string in the first place.

Comment: Don't forget to follow up on your questions. If this solved your question, as mentioned in the comments, then please accept. Currently you've not done this for 3 out of 6 of questions you've got answered!

Answer (score -1):

I might use `String#split` here and just iterate over every letter/number pair:

```
String input = "A= 137, B= 137, C= 138, D= 136, E= 134, F= 138, G= 137";
String[] parts = input.split(",\\s*");
for (String part : parts) {
    String label = part.split("\\s*=\\s*")[0];
    int num = Integer.parseInt(part.split("=\\s*")[1]);
    if (num < 0 || num > 1024) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range value for label: " + label);
    }
}
```

The approach here is to first regex split the string of pairs on `,\s*`, generating an array of strings like `"A= 137"`.  Then, we iterate that array of pairs, and again regex split on \s*=\s* to isolate the number.  Finally, we check that the range of the number fall between 0 and 1024, and if not, we throw an exception.